# OleDB insert query error

Tags: c#, ms-access

Here is my code and I am getting insert error.

Kindly help

```
OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(dbConnection);

cnn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Emp Data] (" +
"EmpID, Active, EmpName, DOJ, DOL, [Next Manager], DOB, Department, Section, Designation, [Father Name], Address, Town, CNIC, Education, [Habib Metro], [Salary PM], EmailID, [JS Bank Account], [Salary on joining], [Last inc Rs], [Last inc Date], [Next of Kin Name], Relation, [Contact No], Comments, [Reason of Leaving], DOC, [Shift Timings], [Off Day 1], [Off Day 2]"
+ ") VALUES (" +
id + ", 'A' , '" + name + "', '" + doj + "', null '" + manager + "', '" + dob + "', '" + dept + "', '" + section + "', '" + desg + "', '" + father + "', '" + add + "', '" + town + "', '" + cnic + "', '" + education + "', '" + metroBank + "', " + salaryPM + ", '" + email + "', '" + jsBank + "', " + salary + ", 0, 0, null, '" + kinName + "', '" + kinRelation + "', '" + kinContact + "', '" + comments + "', null '" + doc + "', '" + shift + "', '" + offDay1 + "', '" + offDay2
+ "');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Pro tip, remove the `<pre>` tags in your post, then highlight all the code and press `CTRL+K`

Comment: Good, that we all are seers and we all know,, what kind of error you are getting. But wait... we are not.... So please state one.

Comment: its throwing exception {"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."}

Comment: With just a glance I can just about guarantee you are making a mistake with concatenating all those variables. Either you have improper quoting or nulls, or both, etc. Use parameterized queries to alleviate these issues and also prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect:

```
null '"
```

should be:

```
null, '"
```

*You are missing a comma in a couple of places.*

Comment: after adding comma it is still not working the query is working but when I am sending query through c# code it throwing error of Syxtax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: Just showing that
<b>Syxtax error in INSERT INTO statement</b>

Comment: No it isn't @RizwanAhmed . That is the `exception`. I want to know the contents of `cmd.CommandText`. Put a breakpoint on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line and tell us what the value of `cmd.CommandText` is. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: the value on execute non query method
The name 'ExecuteNonQuery' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @RizWanAhmed There is absolutely nothing I can do to help if you can't share the contents of `cmd.CommandText`.